# Netbeans swing Master detail sample form delete not working

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, crud, sample

I'm using NB 7.4, JavaDb , jdk 7.

I tried to work on this example : http://simsam7.blogspot.in/2013/06/quick-crud-application-on-netbeans-73.html

In CRUD, CRU works good, but delete not working,and its not throwing any error also.

My Code for delete button.

```
 int[] selected = masterTable.getSelectedRows();
        List<com.fz.PurchaseOrder> toRemove = new ArrayList<com.fz.PurchaseOrder>(selected.length);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < selected.length; idx++) {
            com.fz.PurchaseOrder p = list.get(masterTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selected[idx]));
            toRemove.add(p);
            entityManager.remove(p);
        }
        list.removeAll(toRemove);
```

I done debug, and i think error at entityManager.remove(p).

**INFO :** Output GUI - The row in table removes/delete good, but when i refresh it shows again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by this code. It works, but i'm not sure, is it the right way?

```
int[] selected = masterTable.getSelectedRows();
        List<Products> toRemove = new ArrayList<Products>(selected.length);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < selected.length; idx++) {
            Products p = list.get(masterTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selected[idx]));
            toRemove.add(p);
            entityManager.remove(p);
        }
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        list.removeAll(toRemove);
```

If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: without **try{}catch{}** it throw error. Also only **commit()** throed error for me.

Comment: Thanks, this code works great for me. It also works without putting those 2 lines in a try-catch.